# How to fix prerender error when deploying nextJs on vercel

Tags: next.js, vercel

Locally, I am able to perform `npm run dev`
However, when i try to deploy the code to vercel, I am getting the following error:

```
Error: Export encountered errors on following paths:
    /
    /404
    /500
    at /vercel/path0/node_modules/next/dist/export/index.js:493:19
    at runMicrotasks (<anonymous>)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:95:5)
    at async Span.traceAsyncFn (/vercel/path0/node_modules/next/dist/trace/trace.js:74:20)
    at async /vercel/path0/node_modules/next/dist/build/index.js:970:17
    at async Span.traceAsyncFn (/vercel/path0/node_modules/next/dist/trace/trace.js:74:20)
    at async /vercel/path0/node_modules/next/dist/build/index.js:844:13
    at async Span.traceAsyncFn (/vercel/path0/node_modules/next/dist/trace/trace.js:74:20)
    at async Object.build [as default] (/vercel/path0/node_modules/next/dist/build/index.js:82:25)
```

Answer (score 2):

**How to clearly deploy on vercel**

1. Check you `environment vercel variables` ([info](https://vercel.com/docs/concepts/projects/environment-variables)). Check you set correctly `production` && `preview` && `development` variables.
2. Try `npm run build` locally, if it not works check `point 1`
3. Check `.env` files. Your `.env` files are not exported on github, so vercel can't get data from .env files. This point means you need only store your .env data as `string` and `numbers`, no complex code depending on your environment.
4. Check `errors` and `warnings` at every page vercel will deploy. In the code you shared, you have some problems with `400` and `500` pages
5. Sometimes, if you have DB connected, you can have errors on vercel because your DB can reject a huge number of requests from vercel. Just redeploy your code
6. Inspect `'red'` files in your code editor. For example, in VScode any page showing with red color will `throw vercel error` during deployment, even if your local code works.